# Django: Merging n raw query set results

Tags: django, python-2.7

With the results of a Django raw query set using a query such as this:

```
    for employee in employees:

        staff = Staff.objects.raw('Long query... WHERE employee_id= %s', [employee.id])
```

I created a list, then created a dictionary.

```
     final_list = []

     for s in staff:
         a = {
             'first_name' : s.first_name,
             }

         final_list.append(dict(a))

     print(final_list)
```

Resulting in this:

```
    [{'first_name':u'John'}, {'first_name':u'Jill'}]
    []
    [{'first_name':u'James'}, {'first_name':u'Susan'}]
    [{'first_name':u'Bill'}]
```

How can I merge the results to get something like this:

```
[{'first_name':u'John'}, {'first_name':u'Jill'}, {'first_name':u'James'}, {'first_name':u'Susan'}, {'first_name':u'Bill'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append each `final_list` to another list `final_lists`:

You can concatenate these with *list comprehension*:

```
for employee in employees:
    final_list = []
    staff = Staff.objects.raw('Long query... WHERE employee_id= %s', [employee.id])
    for s in staff:
        a = {
             'first_name' : s.first_name,
        }
        final_list.append(a)
    final_lists.append(final_list)
result = [ li for l in final_lists for li in l ]
```

But the above is not a good idea. You can simply rewrite the query and fetch all the data in one pass:

```
staff = Staff.objects.raw(
    'Long query... WHERE employee_id IN (%s)',
    [[e.id for e in employees]]
)
result = [{'first_name': s.first_name} for s in staff]
```

Usually the performance scales linear with the amount of roundtrips to the database, and thus by fetching all data in a single query, you boost performance.

Actually using raw queries is usually not a good idea: it is less declarative, an ORM can sometimes slightly optimize queries, and if you later change the database dialect, the query automatically talks the other dialect.

Comment: I'm getting the same results when using the list comprehension: [ li for l in final_list for li in l ]. Editing the query results in the following error: "not all arguments converted during string formatting".

Comment: @spaghetti_code: you of course need to *collect* the results of the different iterations...

Comment: The query still give me the same error but the list comprehension worked. Thank you!

Comment: @spaghetti_code: ah, in the query, you need to wrap it in a singleton list. See edit.

Comment: I tried rewriting the query again and got an error ''Operand should contain 1 column(s)'. I think the error would have something to do with the structure of my raw query... The theory behind the answer is sound though.